# Include FXML file in TableView Cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, fxml, uitableview

Is it possible to set a whole **FXML** File with its corresponding controller as a single cell of a **TableView**? I really get no way to do so.

I want to have a TableView with only eight cells, and each of these cells is a **LineChart** and has its own FXML file and controller. For example, one of these cells should be this FXML file:

```
<LineChart xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="control.Channel1Controller"
           fx:id="lineChart1" animated="false" title="Channel 1"
           onMouseClicked="#handleClick"
           onScroll="#handleScroll"
           onContextMenuRequested="#popUpChartContextMenu">
    <xAxis>
        <NumberAxis fx:id="timeAxis" lowerBound="0" upperBound="3000" tickUnit="50"
                    label="Time (ms)"/>
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis fx:id="bandWidthAxis" side="LEFT" lowerBound="0" upperBound="1000" tickUnit="50"
                    label="Band Width (μs)"/>
    </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use specifically a `TableView`? If the number of cells is constant, wouldn't a `GridPane` be better?

Comment: @sillyfly For two reasons. Firstly, for the resizing feature of the TableView. As far as I've understood the resizing is much more straight forward in TableView than in GridPane. And secondly for its style. The selection of charts also matters to me.